# overwrite file on s3 doesn't show on cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I overwrite files I have uploaded to a bucket on S3 and am using cloudfront to then show the files on my site. However they are not updating.. do I need to clear some kind of cache or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to invalidate the cache. Check out the api [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/CreateInvalidation.html)

You write a POST request with an XML body similar to this:

```
POST /2014-11-06/distribution/distribution ID/invalidation HTTP/1.0
Host: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
Authorization: AWS authentication string
Content-Type: text/xml
Other required headers

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvalidationBatch xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2014-11-06/">
   <Paths>
      <Quantity>number of objects to invalidate</Quantity>
      <Items>
         <Path>/path to object to invalidate</Path>
      </Items>
   </Paths>
   <CallerReference>unique identifier for this invalidation batch</CallerReference>
</InvalidationBatch>
```